# Mouse Over effect working only on TextBlock in WPF

Tags: wpf, triggers, grid, textblock

I want to check effect of MouseOver on wpf controls. In my code it is working only on textblock and not on others. Code is correct and no error is generated. Where can I get property values of Triggers ?

```
<Window x:Class="RoutedEventPr.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid Width="200" Height="100" Background="AliceBlue" >
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
    <Ellipse Fill="#FF3AB0B0" StrokeThickness="4" Width="200" Height="100">
        <Ellipse.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect/>
        </Ellipse.Effect>
        <Ellipse.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Ellipse.Style>
    </Ellipse>
    <TextBlock Text="Press" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Try to use eventrigger isntead.

Comment: the issue is that that controls define his own onMouseOver styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `TextBlock` is the only control where you don't set manually the initial value as you do with `Background` against `Grid` and `Fill` against `Ellipse`. If you want `Trigger` to be able to overwrite default value you need to bring it into `Style` as `Setter`

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="100" >
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
    <Ellipse StrokeThickness="4" Width="200" Height="100">
        <Ellipse.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect/>
        </Ellipse.Effect>
        <Ellipse.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF3AB0B0"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Ellipse.Style>
    </Ellipse>
    <TextBlock Text="Press" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

`DependencyProperty` follows source hierarchy and manual value takes priority over `Style`. You can read more under [Dependency Property Setting Precedence List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#listing)

Comment: Perfect ! But is this the way to learn WPF ? Why things are not working as a normal developer would expect them to be ?

Comment: `DependencyProperty` is very important in WPF as it lets you bind and it not only stores the value but source as well, to avoid current value mess, as it can be set via many things like `Style`, `Style.Triggers`, `Template.Triggers`, animations . For example what if during animation `Trigger` could change the value or there is `Style` and `Template` trigger which value to take?

Comment: +1 for your answer. Will keep pinging you for my doubts.

Comment: If you have more problems just post more questions and I'm sure someone will help you here

Comment: Last advice : Which way to go for reading ? Any book which give complete reference or msdn link which you gave is good.

Comment: MSDN has lots of information and provides some explanation besides looking into examples and good project for you to start with WPF.

Comment: Thanks bro, will go through MSDN first , start to finish.